# C# DataTable and PK

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm having such a problem: got dataset with a table(s). Say, we have already several records in a table which has a primary key (autoincrement). Basically, program works fine until I insert a new row. Even I use method AcceptChanges or Update, the new row is commited but it existing datatable object lacks the newest primary key value which I need for furhter processing. Is the only method to reload all the table from database again or there is a better way for it?

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add ';select SCOPE_IDENTITY()' to the end of your insert sql statement attached to your data adapter.  That will read back the last inserted value generated by autoincrement and update your dataset.

I.e, your insert sql should resemble this:

```
insert into sometable(column1,column2) values(@column1,@column2); select * from sometable where primarykeycolumn=scope_identity()
```

Your existing dataset will then contain the primary keys when dataadaper.Update(dataset) returns.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way. Using MS-SQL etc it should be available as a checkbox in the Adapter-designer (Advanced / Refresh table)

Comment: You might want to put your code inside a lock() statement to make it thread safe. It will not however prevent concurrent calls from different processes to get the identity mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a connection object you could use

```
int = (int)conn.executeScalar("SELECT @@IDENTITY")
```

Modified by what datatype your primary key is.

This has to be done directly before any other operations as a new insert will replace the stored value in @@IDENTIY

Comment: I would notice and highlight that such command or the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() should be called immediately after the insert, I would really put it in the stored procedure or in the query statement which does the insert and avoid to have it executed afterwards.